# std::array-like class copy constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm writing code for GPUs, so I can't use STL classes because methods need special annotations to run on the GPU. So, I'm reimplementing `std::array`, with proper annotations (`INLINE`) on its methods. The issue I have right now is my copy constructor calls the assignment operator on members:

```
template <typename T, Int n>
class Few {
  T array_[n];

 public:
  INLINE Few(Few<T, n> const& rhs) {
    for (Int i = 0; i < n; ++i) array_[i] = rhs.array_[i];
  }
};
```

That works okay for simple `T`, but there is a type for which this needs to call the copy constructor, not the assignment operator. How do I get the compiler to copy construct each element in the array ?

Comment: Would [std::uninitialized_copy_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy_n) work?

Comment: @fun4jimmy almost. its not annotated for GPUs, but I copied its implementation and that worked.

Comment: Actually array_ has been default initialised already so it's probably not valid to use uninitialized_copy_n.

Comment: @fun valid, but usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I get the compiler to copy construct each element in the array ?

It already will. That's exactly what the default copy constructor will do here. So just don't provide one yourself, or explicitly default it:

```
Few(Few const& ) = default;
```

Comment: it all comes down to that `INLINE` annotation for GPUs. the default copy construction doesn't have that annotation, so I needed an explicit equivalent.

Answer (score -3):

It seems like using the placement-new operator worked out. I'm not sure this is completely legit per the C++ standard, but here it is:

```
  INLINE Few(Few<T, n> const& rhs) {
    for (Int i = 0; i < n; ++i) new (array_ + i) T (rhs.array_[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Iff you need to call placement-new, you probably also should call the dtor manually.

Comment: What happens if type T's default constructor allocates some memory? I think calling placement new on an already initialised value would cause it to leak?

Comment: This solution is correct if and only if you switch to `std::aligned_storage_t<T[n]> array;` or `alignas(T) char array[n * sizeof(T)];`. If you have `T array[n];` then calling placement new is undefined behavior becaue the compiler calls default constructors on the same objects just before.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not undefined. You just construct new objects in their place and end the lifetime of the old ones without running their destructors, which is allowed as long as you don't depend on those destructors' side effects.

Comment: @T.C. This is interesting. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [basic.life], in particular [/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#5).

Comment: Yes, I agree about the constructor calls. again, I hesitate to use `std::aligned_storage_t` for annotation reasons, but maybe I should do the `char array[n * sizeof(T)]` thing to be fully safe.